# Trying to point to object in class constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, object, pointers, constructor

I have this C++ code for my class DoubleKnob. I'm trying to have the class connect to a specific object of the class KnobLook that is specified when the DoubleKnob object is created. I am getting no errors in the object creation code and the KnobLook object is created before this one, but in this class I am getting the error that lookFeel is undefined in the lines with xMin and xMax. Do you know why?

```
class DoubleKnob : public Knob
{
public:
    DoubleKnob(KnobLook& lookFeel) { ; }
    int xMin = lookFeel.xMin;
    int xMax = lookFeel.xMax;
};
```

I also tried this code, copying the type of stuff that my framework code does, and got the "unresolved external symbol" error:

```
class DoubleKnob : public Knob
{
public:
    DoubleKnob(KnobLook&);
    KnobLook& lookFeel;

    int xMin = lookFeel.xMin;
    int xMax = lookFeel.xMax;
};
```

I'm not putting the xMin and xMax in the constructor because certain functions are going to have those reset to whatever lookFeel.xMin or lookFeel.xMax is at that time.

Comment: Why aren't the assignments inside the contructor function?

Comment: `lookFeel` is a parameter of the constructor, you can't refer to it outside the function.

Comment: The assignments aren't in the constructor because they will be updated periodically by other functions.

Comment: In the second version `DoubleKnob(KnobLook&);` is only a constructor declaration, but is missing a definition (a function body)

Comment: How do I make it so I can refer to what is in the constructor outside of that function?

Comment: Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: @gorilla No. The _assignments_ must be in the constructor, the variables need to stay class members and can still be accessed from outside.

Comment: The xMin and xMin are periodically going to be set by the expression xMin = lookFeel.xMin I'm trying to make it so I can point to the lookFeel object at any point in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the member variables outside the contructor, but assign them in the constructor.

If you want a reference to the `lookfeel` variable to persist, make that a member variable.

```
class DoubleKnob : public Knob
{
public:
    KnobLook &lookFeel;
    DoubleKnob(KnobLook& lookFeel) : lookFeel{ lookFeel } {}
};
```

Then you can refer to `lookFeel.xMin` and `lookFeel.xMax` in other member functions.

Comment: How would I make it so I can set xMin to equal lookFeel.xMin in later functions? lookFeel.xMin is constantly changing and I want that value to be transferred over to this class after certain user input.

Comment: You should have a `KnobLook` member variable.

Comment: When I try this:
class DoubleKnob : public Knob
{
public:
    KnobLook& lookFeel;
    DoubleKnob(KnobLook& lookFeels) { lookFeel = lookFeels; }

    int xMin = lookFeel.xMin;
    int xMax = lookFeel.xMax;
};

I get unresolved external symbol error again.

Comment: You keep trying to reference variables outside the function that declares them.